# Nginx Reverse Proxy esotic request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Is possible to proxify external site with nginx like this:

server_name www.clientsite.com clientsite.com;

...

proxy_pass http://www.externalsite.com/;

This is the unique request of my client. He wants to do with caching for external links to your site for faster loading ... I have no ideas, I tried it and it works with some sites and some do not. Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It should work that way. If your client needs caching, why not use a dedicated cache tool like `varnish`? It has a config language that is very powerful (when you finally understand it). The website is https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Comment: and varnish may make an exotic configuration as that required? Can you please show me an example? Thanks for response

Comment: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#examples

Comment: with nginx nothing?